# Привязать метод к Binding Path

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь создать трей меню, все добавляется, как нужно, но загвоздка в том что я не понимаю как добавить в меню ссылку (например) на нажатие кнопки (метод уже имеется в главном окне)

```
    <MenuItem Header="MENU1"
    Command="{Commands:HideSampleWindowCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding}">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Width="16"
                   Height="16"
                   Source="/Resources/popUp/Images/contextMenu_uninstall_on.png" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>


public class HideSampleWindowCommand : CommandBase<HideSampleWindowCommand>
{
    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        GetTaskbarWindow(parameter).Hide();
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        Window win = GetTaskbarWindow(parameter);
        return win != null && win.IsVisible;
    }
}
```

Этот код позволяет сворачивать окно. Как мне реализовать свои действия?

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть два пути. Либо вы кладёте экземпляр класса, реализующего команду, в DataContext или его свойство. Либо создаёте экземпляр класса, реализующего команду, в ресурсы, и подключаете его через StaticResource.

Для случая отсутствия DataContext:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Commands:HideSampleWindowCommand x:Key="HSWCommand" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <!-- ... -->

    <MenuItem Command="{StaticResource HSWCommand}" ... />
```

Comment: К сожалению я не совсем Вас понял(

Comment: @МаксФадеев: Ну, вы вы устанавливаете DataContext?

Comment: нет, у меня в главной форме установлен <libs1:TaskbarIcon
            x:Name="tb"
            ContextMenu="{StaticResource tbMenu}"
        </libs1:TaskbarIcon>

Comment: @МаксФадеев: Добавил код в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую